# impose Specific property to particular modal only

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I wanted to make a modal and by default size of modal was small so i used modal-content class to increase it's height and width but this specification was given to all modals automatically  used in project but i want this size for this modal only .

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Map</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <MapsDataCollection/>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-content{
    height:35em !important;
    width:130% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
From React Bootstrap -- Modal

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-props

Try editing the size attribute on `Modal` could help

Comment: using size the header is getting large not body part

Answer (score 0):

use contentClassName="custom-modal-style" and make changes in this class

```
<Modal 
                    contentClassName="custom-modal-style"
                    show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Map</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <MapsDataCollection/>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).